# remote connection to Ksql server

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have a ksql server running on an ec2 instance and I want to connect to it from my local machine. However, it always keeps throwing the following error:

```
Error issuing GET to KSQL server
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Caused by: Could not connect to the server.
```

I have modified my security group's settings to allow inbound traffic on the required port (on which the server is running). I am also able to telnet on the port from my local. Any leads on this will be very helpful!! Thanks!

Comment: starting the server on 0.0.0.0:8088 enables the connection but with localhost it keeps struggling.

Comment: Sounds like you’ve answered your own question? The KSQL server needs to be listening on an address that is accessible externally, which `localhost` won’t be. Let me know if you still need help with this.

Comment: @RichaBanker if the issue is fixed, considering answering your own question. It will be easier to see the solution as an answer than as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

starting the server on `0.0.0.0:8088` solves the problem.

Comment: I can login to the server, but, this still doesn't solve the problem for me